# Tangent cone of an arbitrary algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, tangent-line, singularity, singularity-theory

So, my problem is: given a real/complex (I will assume complex) algebraic curve, say $f(x,y)$, or $f(z,w)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ or $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ (I would like to hear your thoughts in either case), and let's assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=0$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=0$ at the point $(x_0,y_0)$; in other words, $(x_0,y_0)$ is defining a singularity, assuming $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the locus of $f$.

I want to find the equations for the tangent lines at $(x_0,y_0)$. A few examples I am interested in are:

1.) $f=xy+x+y+1$

2.) $f=x^3-x^2+y^2$

3.) $f=x^3+x^2+y^2$

4.) $f=2x^4-3x^2y+y^2-2y^3+y^4$

I read about a definition here: [Tangents at singularities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626745/tangents-at-singularities), but was unable to figure out how to use it computationally. Additionally, I read about a "minimal homogeneous degree" here: [Compute tangent cone from a given ideal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708248/compute-tangent-cone-from-a-given-ideal), but was unable to figure out what was meant, particularly in case "1.)"

I would appreciate any references, thoughts, and or ideas that you have! Ultimately, I am trying to teach myself about the classification of singular points. I have been using "Walker, Robert John. Algebraic Curves. Dover, 1962." along with other papers I have found on the internet and the maple "algcurves" package and the "singularities" command in it. Here are some links for those:

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=algcurves%2Fsingularities,

[https://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/algcurves.html](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ehoeij/algcurves.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(-1,-1)$
   $$(x+1)(y+1)=0$$
2. $(0,0)$
   $$y^2-x^2=(y+x)(y-x)=0$$
3. $(0,0)$
   $$y^2+x^2=(y+ix)(y-ix)=0$$
4. $(0,0)$
   $$2x^4-3x^2y+y^2-2y^3+y^4=0$$

$$y^2=0$$

4. $(0,1)$
   $$(y-1)^4+2(y-1)^3+(y-1)^2-3x^2(y-1)+2x^4-3x^2=0$$

$$(y-1)^2-3x^2=0$$

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the answer! I think I see what is going on, but wanted to ask. Can you describe a little on what you did to find these solutions, or direct me to a source where I can read about it? How would you go about this for an arbitrary complex algebraic curve assuming there is a singularity at $x_0$, $y_0$?

Comment: @Sora8DTL For an arbitrary plane curve with equation $p(x,y)=0$ with a singularity at $x_0,y_0$ translate to the origin: $p(x+x_0,y+y_0)=0$ and keep only the lowest degree terms.

Comment: Even if the point is not singular but still on the curve (as witnessed by the vanishing constant term when translating to the origin), you'll get the tangent line.

Comment: One source is GTM 133, Joe Harris, Algebraic Geometry, A First Course, Section 20. But also GTM 197, Eisenbud & Harris, The Geometry of Schemes.

Comment: thanks so much for the clarification and references! That helps a lot!