# How to calculate Delta Invariant of of algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity, invariant-theory, singularity-theory

I recently asked a question regarding tangent cones here: [Tangent cone of an arbitrary algebraic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598303/tangent-cone-of-an-arbitrary-algebraic-curve)

After doing some reading, I have another question on how to calculate the delta invariant of these curves. Specifically,I mean the delta invariant referenced here: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=algcurves%2Fsingularities.

I have read that this has something to do with blowing up the curve, but I do not know how to do this for a given curve. I am trying to learn about the classification of singularities if that is any help.

I have repeated the same curve examples from the other question here to illustrate examples.

1.) $f=xy+x+y+1$

2.) $f=x^3-x^2+y^2$

3.) $f=x^3+x^2+y^2$

4.) $f=2x^4-3x^2y+y^2-2y^3+y^4$

Any **thoughts/considerations/references** would be wonderful. Specifically I love examples. So a reference where the author does a calculation would be incredibly useful to me.

Thanks so much!